# Error while injecting @ngx-translate/core using Injector.create

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I am injecting TranslateService from [@ngx-translate/core](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) in my `fc.helper.ts` like this.

```
const injector = Injector.create({
  providers: [{ provide: TranslateService, deps: [] }],
});
const translate: TranslateService = injector.get(TranslateService);
```

and am calling it in my `fc.helper.ts` like this.

```
const cloneCourse = translate.instant('calendar.cloneCourse');
```

And I get an error like

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'translations')
> at get translations [as translations] (ngx-translate-core.mjs:346:63)
> at TranslateService.instant (ngx-translate-core.mjs:580:45)
> ...

What could be wrong with my injection?

Using,

1. @angular/core: 13.3.3
2. @ngx-translate/core: 14.0.0

P.S: @ngx-translate/core constructor injection `constructor(private translate: TranslateService)` works well used elsewhere(i.e., services and components)

Comment: I think you must firstly provide the  TranslateModule.forRoot()